# Merge takeoff and landing tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I propose that we merge the takeoff and landing tags into one [takeoff-landing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/takeoff-landing) tag with a tag synonyms that is reversed. I can't really see someone wanting to follow just one or the other and they are often referred to together anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure I agree... the concepts are *very* different, and I can see the questions being pretty divergent within the one tag.

If somebody is looking for questions about short-field takeoffs, they probably aren't interested in soft-field landings. At least, not right away.

Comment: Asking is different, they can tag it either way we do it.  People who are following and answering questions are probably equally interested in both though.  I doubt that there will be many (any?) takeoff or landing only specialists who will only answer one or the other types of questions.

Comment: I also lean towards separate tags. I don't think "would someone want to follow x but not y?" is the right metric for determining which tags to merge. Tags should represent concepts, not groupings of interests.

Comment: Separate tags makes more sense to me too - takeoff / landing & "qualifiers" (short-field , soft-field, reduced-power, glassy-water, etc.). Someone might conceivably ask about "soft-field takeoff landing", but separate tags there doesn't hurt anything - you can follow as many tags as you want :-)

Comment: @voretaq7: Do you think that the specific types of landings (soft-field, etc.) will have enough questions to warrant their own tag, or would landings limit the scope enough to find what you are looking for by simply adding key-words to the search?

Comment: @lnafziger I think "landings" is enough personally, but I'm not opposed to the qualifier tags just because they may be low-volume. Also since they're a part of the US PPL requirements I expect those tags will get some use

Comment: @voretaq7: My suggestion is to just start with "landings" and then we can break them out further if needed down the road....

Comment: @lnafziger I wouldn't try to artificially limit tagging - if someone *correctly* tags a question with [tag:soft-field] or [tag:short-field] or [tag:seaplane] or something similar it doesn't hurt anything, and it can only increase the discoverability of the question. (Of course the opposite is true too: If a tag isn't appropriate/useful on a question it should certainly be removed.)